# Node.js + MySQL: Double "?" Placeholder

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm making a time card app.

but `const updatesql = "UPDATE users SET ? WHERE ?";`  does not work well...

How to use MySQL's PlaceHolder and Node.js ?
Especially, double placeholder `SET ? WHERE ?` .

```
const checksql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
const checkname = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE name = ";

const updatesql = "UPDATE users SET ? WHERE ?";

if (req.body.begin_button) {
  var name_checked = await query(checksql,{ name: 
  req.body.input_name });
  var status_checked = await query(checkname,{ name: req.body.input_name});

  if (name_checked == 0) {
    var results = await query(sql, { id: id, name: 
    req.body.input_name, email: req.body.input_mail, start: now, status: 1 });
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  };
} else if (req.body.finish_button){
  if (name_checked != 0){
    var results = await query(updatesql, { end: now, status: 0});
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }
} else if (req.body.start_button) {
  if (status_checked == 1) {
    var results = await query(updatesql, {restbegin: now,status: 2 });
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  };
} else if (req.body.end_button) {
  if (status_checked == 2) {
    var results = await query(updatesql, { restend: now, status: 3 });
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = ? OR address = ?';
con.query(sql, [name, adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank for your help :D